# www-data user crontab not working

Tags: php, ubuntu, cron

I created a crontab -e under my username `raheel` and it is working fine. The task is to delete some files from web server everyday. The owner and group of those files is `www-data`. So its not deleting. I am now trying to run this cron job for this purpose i created a cron se follows

```
sudo crontab -u www-data -e
```

and put my command in this file. This is supposed to be the crontab for apache user www-data but nothing is happening. How can i see is it even running or not or what is going on behind.

THanks

Comment: Did you tried to delete a file with your username directly (no crontab)?  Did it work?

Comment: Hi, I have the same issue. did you find a solution to it?